# environment regeneration, the right usage of phrase

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

Is it natural way to say:

> He takes steps to help environment in regeneration.

thanks.

Comment: It's ***a*** way.  "He" helps the "environment".  What seems strange to you?

Comment: You could say "*preserve* the environment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a grammar error.

I would say:

> He takes steps to help **the** environment in regeneration.

[Watch out for that "the"!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_article)

Otherwise, the sentence is fine.

Even then, most native speakers usually omit the regeneration when talking about the environment, figuring it out from context unless they are explicitly talking about regeneration.

> He is taking steps to help the environment.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is grammatically correct and makes sense, but it sounds more natural to ad an article before "environment".

> He takes steps to help **the** environment in regeneration.

Use of a [definite article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_article) is important in this sentence if you want to sound like a native speaker:

> A definite article indicates that its noun is a particular one which
>   is identifiable to the listener.